# Spring Integration: pass-through custom http header converted to lowercase

Tags: spring-integration

My application is supposed to pass through a custom http header, hence I tell the inbound http gateway to map that header as request and response header:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows
       .from(Http.inboundGateway("/myresource/{transactionId}")
         .mappedRequestHeaders("X-My-Header", 
             HTTP_REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN)
         .mappedResponseHeaders("X-My-Header", 
             HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN)
    ...
```

The header gets passed through alright, but it is converted to lowercase, i.e. I find x-my-header in the response. I know that http headers are case-insensitive, still I would prefer to keep the header in its original form. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According HTTP RFC headers are case-insensitive, therefore the logic in your app has to be changed to ignore case for those names.

Tomcat team suggests to implement a custom `Filter` to override response headers: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58464.

Anyway I would reconsider a client app logic do not deal with case. Nothing to do with Spring Integration though.

Comment: However, according to the comment (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58464#c2), we cannot predict which letters would be lowercase and which would be uppercase to go with the custom filter approach. It makes it impossible to pass the header names exactly as sent in the original request to the backend.